# How to convert this for loop into a dict comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I can achieve this with

```
mydict = {}
for a in range(0,6):
    mydict[a] = []

print (mydict)

#{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}
```

Question is how would I achieve this with dict comprehension?

Edit:

```
d = {level: [] for level in range(1, level + 1)}

for each_level in d:
    d[each_level] = [ExampleClass(1, 1)
                         for _ in range(5)]
```

Sorry for not putting up what I had from the beginning, I thought it would not be much help.

This is what I have and it does what I want it to be but I am wondering if there is a way I can shorten all of this into one line or so.

In the end, I would like something like:

```
d = {level: [] for level in range(1, level + 1), [ExampleClass(1, 1) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: Explaining the downvotes to you: The question is clear, but you could have tried some dict comprehensions yourself and explained where the problem was.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
d = {a:[] for a in range(6)}
```

Don't use the name `dict` for your own variables, you will shadow the built in name `dict`.
Also note that if you don't supply the `start` argument to `range`, it defaults to `0`.

You might also want to look into the `defaultdict` from the `collections` module instead of initializing a `dict` with empty lists yourself. Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d[0]
[]
>>> d[1]
[]
```

The lists are only instantiated when you access a key for the first time.

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [], 1: []})
```

edit: **~follow up~**

I don't have your example class, but you should be able to learn the necessary synatx from this demo. `slice` will step in for your `ExampleClass`.

```
>>> ExampleClass = slice
>>> d = {a:[ExampleClass(1, 1) for _ in range(5)] for a in range(6)}
>>> d
{0: [slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None)], 1: [slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None)], 2: [slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None)], 3: [slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None)], 4: [slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None)], 5: [slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None)]}
```

Comment: How can I go one step foward and run a for loop for my values as well?

Comment: @Pikachu I don't quite understand the follow up question. Can you salvage your question by including a [MCVE], please?

Comment: @Pikachu: Do you want something like this: `d = {a:list(range(1, 4)) for a in range(6)}`?

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes I did and i edited the OP. sorry about that.